# Calculate Similarity using User's Personal Data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, similarity, cosine-similarity

I want to find out which users are similar to each other using their personal/organisational data, such as department, company, site, etc.

I have this data in a boolean format, as shown below:

```
       Dep1 Dep2 Comp1 Comp2 Site1 Site2
    U1  0    1     0     1     0     1
    U2  1    0     0     1     1     0
    U3  1    0     1     0     1     0
    U4  0    1     0     1     0     1
    U5  0    1     0     1     1     0
    U6  1    0     1     0     0     1
```

I want to select a user and identify the other users that are similar to them, so that I can recommend them software/hardware that those similar users are using.

I have looked into Cosine and Jaccard similarity but I have not seen much help when it comes to calculating them on Boolean data.

I'm using Python and am not new to the language, but I am fairly new to Data Analytics and ML. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: You could just count the number of equal columns instead. So the similarity score between U1 and U2 is only 1 and between U2 and U3 is 2 etc.

Comment: If you want to find similarity based on text, Word2Vec might help you. Applications of Word Embedding :

>> Sentiment Analysis
>> Speech Recognition
>> Information Retrieval
>> Question Answering

Comment: @DaanKlijn I suppose that could be a good solution. I have a dataframe with 3000+ columns and 61k rows, so it could be a fairly intensive algorithm. Do you have any advice on how to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, as you already mentioned calculating the similarity between 60k different users will be quite intensive. This would result in a a similarity matrix of 60k*60k rows, for which I doubt if it would fit into your systems memory. If possible I would try to group your users by something like department or site (if that makes sense). And then only compare users to users within their group so you don't have to compare all 60k against the other 60k.

To keep the computation reasonably fast I would do a matrix multiplication using numpy to perform the similarity calculation. You could simply count the number of equal 1's using the following matrix multiplication:

```
import numpy as np

df = np.random.randint(low = 2,size=(5000,3000))
similarities = df.dot(df.T)
```

This finishes on my laptop within 60 seconds. The result will be a 5000 * 5000 matrix containing the similarity between all the 5000 rows of the df.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to make a recommendation system. Since you explictly asked for cosine similarity,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.txt')

# calculate the cosine similarity - there are many other metrices
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
res = cosine_similarity(df)

# to visualize the similarity matrix as a heatmap
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=[list(item) for item in res],
    x = df.index.values,
    y = df.index.values))
fig.show()
```

[image]